# chemmacros reaction environment and cleveref reference

Tags: cleveref, chemmacros

I have a problem with the automatic reference by [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) and the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package. When i refer to a reaction with cleveref, then cleveref types "eq. (1)" because `chemmacros` use the equation environment. That's why a simple customization with \crefname, \creflabelformat or \crefformat has no effects. But i want, that cleveref detect the reaction and set the reference to `reaction {1}`.
Here the MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
Before a little text.
\begin{reaction}
A -> B \label{rxn:test}
\end{reaction}
After the ref with cleveref \cref{rxn:test}.
\end{document}
```

The cleveref package provides an advanced \label-command with a optional argument to overwrite the reference type.

```
\begin{reaction}
A -> B \label[reaction]{rxn:test}
\end{reaction}
```

Gives

> ```
> A -> Breaction]rxn:test
> ```

But no erros and correct reference output. According to the cleveref documentation, you should use the folliwing code for the optional \label-command

```
\begin{reaction}
A -> B {\label[reaction]{rxn:test}}
\end{reaction}
```

Gives me 3 times the error

> ```
> amsmath: Multiple \label's: label '[reaction]{rxn:test}' will be lost. \end{reaction}
> ```

But with a \crefname{reaction}{reaction}{reactions} and \creflabelformat{reaction}{#2{#1}#3} the reference output is correct.

During the investigations i found out, that with this code (add a 1 to the labeltag)

```
\begin{reaction}
A -> B {\label[reaction]{rxn:test1}}
\end{reaction}
```

several errors come and no correct ref output.

> ```
> Undefined control sequence ...n:test\chemformula_subscript:n {1}}{{1}{1}}
>
> Undefined control sequence ...ubscript:n {1}@cref}{{[reaction][3][]1}{1}}
>
> amsmath: Multiple \label's: label '[reaction]{rxn:test\chemformula_subscript:n {1}}' will be lost. \end{reaction}
>
> Undefined control sequence ...n:test\chemformula_subscript:n {1}}{{1}{1}}
>
> Undefined control sequence ...ubscript:n {1}@cref}{{[reaction][4][]1}{1}}
> ```

chemmacros define the reaction by the [`environ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ). chemmacros or environ processes the optional \label-command incorrect.

Does anyone have an idea to connect chemmacros with cleveref? Thanks!

Comment: It seems that chemmacros interprets the label like a subscript from a formula -> \chemformula_subscript:n

Comment: I know of the wrapper attribute. I studied the *.sty of chemmacros and cleveref 2 hours. So, therefore I thing is better to fix the reaction environment that the cleveref label command works, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With version 4.5 (2014/04/08) `chemmacros` supports an optional argument to `\label`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}[2014/04/08]

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{reaction}{reaction}{reactions}
\creflabelformat{reaction}{#2\{#1\}#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
  A -> B \label[reaction]{rct:ab}
\end{reaction}

See \cref{rct:ab}\ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update 2016-11-26**

Since v5.6 `chemmacros` has native support for `cleveref`. The code for the picture above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}[2016/05/02]
\usechemmodule{reactions}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
  A -> B \label{rct:ab}
\end{reaction}

See \cref{rct:ab}\ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: The Problem regarding a number in the label still exists. Are there any plans to fix this too?

Comment: @Niklas put the whole label in between `"..." `

Comment: I don't know back there, but the current documentation (2022) says that for cleveref we must use `"\label{rxn:my-reaction}"`, `rct` is for fancyref and I think for hyperref? but surely `rxn -> cleveref; rct -> fancyref`

Comment: @EduardoJiménez `rct` is used by `fancyref` through `\def\fancyrefrctlabelprefix{rct}`. Neither `hyperref` nor `cleveref` care about the prefix